# How to prevent longtable to put header alone in one page

Tags: positioning, longtable

How to prevent longtable to put header alone in one page like in image below. I used `endhead` to prevent this but this will print the header on each page.

[image]

Sorry I don't give **MWE** because I haven't succeeded to reproduce it with minimum data.

Comment: hard to say without an example (It should be easy to generate an example from your test document just by removing things that are not needed and using a `\vspace*{5cm}` or where to simulate the point where LT starts on the first page. If that definition line is not in a heading and is just a normal row you could end the row with \\* to discourage a break (but that doesn't really work if you have \hline as that re-allows the break, or put that ro and a copule more rows in an \endfirsthead so they are never split, but not copied

Comment: or just put `\clearpage` before the table (before the heading, probably)

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135956/how-to-prevent-page-break-between-section-title-and-table/135958#135958

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As noted in

[How to prevent page break between section title and table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135956/how-to-prevent-page-break-between-section-title-and-table/135958#135958)

You could use the `needspace` package to conditionally ad a `\clearpage` if the heading is near the bottom of the page. (The problem that is solving is slightly different, a page break happening before the table, after the heading, whereas you have a page break within the heading).

In general though, the simplest way in `longtable` to ensure that the first one or two lines of the table body stick to the first table head is to put the `\endfirsthead` line *after* those lines. You may think of them as part of the table body but if you want them always to stick with the head, putting them in the head works well. Similarly you can if needed put the last line or two into the top of the `\endlastfoot` so that they stay with the table footer at the end of the table.