# How to prevent pagebreak between section/subsection title

Tags: sectioning, page-breaking, titles, paracol

How to prevent pagebreaks between section/subsection titles and the multicolumn content of the document when using the [paracol](https://ctan.org/pkg/paracol) environment  like this...

```
\renewcommand{\deutschertitel}{Dezimalsystem}
\renewcommand{\englischertitel}{Decimal System}

\subsection[\englischertitel]{}

\begin{paracol}{2}[]

\subsection*{\englischertitel}

\switchcolumn

\subsection*{\deutschertitel}

\switchcolumn*

The decimal system uses...

\switchcolumn

Das Dezimalsystem verwendet...

\end{paracol}
```

Here is one example that shows a page break where it should not happen:

[image: An example that shows a page break where it should not happen]

Another example that shows a page break where it should not happen:

[image: Another example that shows a page break where it should not happen]

**Update (2019-01-23):**

Added a better source code example and some screenshots that show the issue.

Comment: Please add an MWE to the question.

Comment: It's preferable to put the "Solution" into the answer box, so that it can be upvoted appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that worked for me very well is using `\Needspace` which is described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135956/how-to-prevent-page-break-between-section-title-and-table?rq=1) very well. A `\Needspace{1.9cm}` before every `\section` command and a `\Needspace{2.2cm}` before every `\subsection` command fixed the issue for me without the need of inserting any `\pagebreaks`.